# R conditional lookup and sum

Tags: r, sapply

I have data on college course completions, with estimated numbers of students from each cohort completing after 1, 2, 3, ... 7 years. I want to use these estimates to calculate the total number of students outputting from each College and Course in any year.

The output of students in a given year will be the sum of the previous 7 cohorts outputting after 1, 2, 3, ... 7 years.

For example, the number of students outputting in 2014 from COLLEGE 1, COURSE A is equal to the sum of:

```
Output of 2013 cohort (College 1, Course A) after 1 year +
Output of 2012 cohort (College 1, Course A) after 2 years +
Output of 2011 cohort (College 1, Course A) after 3 years +
Output of 2010 cohort (College 1, Course A) after 4 years +
Output of 2009 cohort (College 1, Course A) after 5 years +
Output of 2008 cohort (College 1, Course A) after 6 years +
Output of 2007 cohort (College 1, Course A) after 7 years +
```

So there are two dataframes: a lookup table that contains all the output estimates, and a smaller summary table that I'm trying to modify. I want to update dummy.summary$output with, for each row, the total output based on the above calculation.

The following code will replicate my data pretty well

```
# Lookup table
dummy.lookup <- data.frame(cohort = rep(1998:2014, each = 210),
           college = rep(rep(paste("College", 1:6), each = 35), 17),
           course = rep(rep(paste("Course", LETTERS[1:5]), each = 7),102),
           intake = rep(sample(x = 150:300, size = 510, replace=TRUE), each = 7),
           output.year = rep(1:7, 510),
           output = sample(x = 10:20, size = 3570, replace=TRUE))


# Summary table to be modified
dummy.summary <- aggregate(x = dummy.lookup["intake"], by = list(dummy.lookup$cohort, dummy.lookup$college, dummy.lookup$course), FUN = mean)
names(dummy.summary)[1:3] <- c("year", "college", "course")
dummy.summary <- dummy.summary[order(dummy.summary$year, dummy.summary$college, dummy.summary$course), ]
dummy.summary$output <- 0
```

The following code does not work, but shows the approach I've been attempting.

dummy.summary$output <- sapply(dummy.summary$output, function(x){

```
    # empty vector to fill with output values
    vec <- c()

    # Find relevant output for college + course, from each cohort and exit year
    for(j in 1:7){

      append(x = vec,
             values = dummy.lookup[dummy.lookup$college==dummy.summary[x, "college"] &
                                     dummy.lookup$course==dummy.summary[x, "course"] &
                                     dummy.lookup$cohort==dummy.summary[x, "year"]-j &
                                     dummy.lookup$output.year==j, "output"])

    }

    # Sum and return total output
    sum_vec <- sum(vec)

    return(sum_vec)

  }
    )
```

I guess it doesn't work because I was hoping to use 'x' in the anonymous function to index particular values of the dummy.summary dataframe. But that clearly isn't happening and is only returning zero for each row, presumably because the starting value of 'x' is zero each time. I don't know if it is possible to access the *index position* of each value that sapply loops over, and use that to index my summary dataframe.

Is this approach fixable or do I need a completely different approach?

Even if it is fixable, is there a more elegant/faster way to acheive what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just updated your `output.year` to `output.year2` where instead of a value from 1 to 7 it gets a value of a year based on the `cohort` you have.

I've realised that the `output` information you want corresponds to the `output.year`, but the `intake` information you want corresponds to the `cohort`. So, I calculate them separately and then I join tables/information. This automatically creates empty (NA that I transform to 0) `output` info for 1998.

```
# fix your random sampling
set.seed(24)  

# Lookup table
dummy.lookup <- data.frame(cohort = rep(1998:2014, each = 210),
                           college = rep(rep(paste("College", 1:6), each = 35), 17),
                           course = rep(rep(paste("Course", LETTERS[1:5]), each = 7),102),
                           intake = rep(sample(x = 150:300, size = 510, replace=TRUE), each = 7),
                           output.year = rep(1:7, 510),
                           output = sample(x = 10:20, size = 3570, replace=TRUE))
dummy.lookup$output[dummy.lookup$yr %in% 1:2] <- 0


library(dplyr)


# create result table for output info
dt_output = 
  dummy.lookup %>%
  mutate(output.year2 = output.year+cohort) %>%     # update output.year to get a year value
  group_by(output.year2, college, course) %>%       # for each output year, college, course
  summarise(SumOutput = sum(output)) %>%            # calculate sum of intake
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(college,course,output.year2) %>%          # for visualisation purposes
  rename(cohort = output.year2)                     # rename column


# create result for intake info
dt_intake =
  dummy.lookup %>%
  select(cohort, college, course, intake) %>%     # select useful columns
  distinct()                                      # keep distinct rows/values


# join info
dt_intake %>% 
  full_join(dt_output, by=c("cohort","college","course")) %>%
  mutate(SumOutput = ifelse(is.na(SumOutput),0,SumOutput)) %>%
  arrange(college,course,cohort) %>%     # for visualisation purposes
  tbl_df()       # for printing purposes


# Source: local data frame [720 x 5]
# 
# cohort   college   course intake SumOutput
# (int)    (fctr)   (fctr)  (int)     (dbl)
# 1    1998 College 1 Course A    194         0
# 2    1999 College 1 Course A    198        11
# 3    2000 College 1 Course A    223        29
# 4    2001 College 1 Course A    198        45
# 5    2002 College 1 Course A    289        62
# 6    2003 College 1 Course A    163        78
# 7    2004 College 1 Course A    211        74
# 8    2005 College 1 Course A    181       108
# 9    2006 College 1 Course A    277       101
# 10   2007 College 1 Course A    157       109
# ..    ...       ...      ...    ...       ...
```

Comment: Thanks @AntoniosK. These look too high - the output in 1999 for College 1 Course A could only be the students from the 1998 cohort (College 1 Course A) exiting after 1 year. In the data here, that would be somewhere between 10 and 20. I'm going to edit question and change the name of dummy.summary$cohort to dummy.summary$year in case this has caused confusion.

Comment: That means I got confused in my first `sum`. Your initial table has 7 rows of `College 1` and `Course 1` and each line has an `output` value in the 10-20 range as you said. What info should I use from those 7 rows?

Comment: It depends which year you are calculating the output total for. If you're calculating output in 1999 from College 1 Course A , then you only have a single number in the data to use - the output from the 1998 cohort at `output.year`==1. But if you were calculating output  in 2005 you would sum the outputs from cohort 2004 at `output.year`==1, cohort 2003 at `output.year`==2, cohort 2002 at `output.year`==3... cohort 1998 at `output.year`==7.

Comment: This is looking really good. I take it we can drop `CohortSumOutput` as SumOutput gives the correct output numbers? Also is it possible to retain the `intake` figure for each row in the final output and show zeros for 1998 output, to look more like my dummy.summary table?

Comment: For each row you'll get the `SumOutput`. What value you want for `intake`? For example, the 2nd row has a `SumOutput` 29 (= 15+14 from two other rows who have intake as 194 and 198).

Comment: Intake for first three rows would be 1999=198, 2000=223, 2001=198 from the original dummy.lookup data. 1998 had an intake (194) but doesn't appear in your solution as there are no outputs you can calculate for 1998. The idea of dummy.summary is to show for each year how many started the course, and how many finished it (from previous intakes). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89288/discussion-between-peter-w-and-antoniosk).

Comment: Almost perfect! Outputs for 2015-2021 aren't included in the final joined table. Using full_join instead seems to preserve everything from 1998 to 2021, correctly showing NA for intakes 2015 onwards. If you agree with that modification could you please edit your answer and I'll accept?

Comment: Yes indeed. `full_join` is the correct command as years 2015-2021 do not exist in the first table (`intake` info) but only in the second table (`output` info).